# message of "Log rev,s (tags/8000.123^0):" in magit

Tags: magit

I am using magit in spacemacs 105.7. When I press `l l` from the `magit-status` buffer to list the commit history, it pops out "Log rev,s (tags/8000.123^0):" in the mini buffer, and when I press enter, then it will list all the commits. Why does this message pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally <kbd>l l</kbd> shows the log for the current branch. But you checked out something that isn't a local branch, so there currently isn't a current branch ("HEAD is detached"). In that case <kbd>l l</kbd> falls back to asking you what log you want to see, defaulting to the log for the commit at point.